# get value of a specific row of a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I get a specific row value of a table(for exampe third row of fifth column) using jquery.
I tried:

```
var t = document.getElementById('table');

    var val1 =$(t.rows[2].cells[4]).val();
    alert(val1);
```

But it is showing nothing

Comment: *"for exampe third row of fifth column"* - Does that mean the fifth column itself contains many rows? or did you mean "5th column in 3rd row"??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector at this context

`.val()` is only applicable for input elements, you should use `.text()` instead to retrieve its text content,

```
var val1 =$(t).find('tr:eq(2) td:eq(4)').text();
alert(val1);
```

Or do,

```
alert($('#table tr:eq(2) td:eq(4)').text());
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/58/)

Answer (score 4):

`.val` is for textBox, textAreas, use `.text` instead like bellow.

That should be something like bellow

```
alert($('table tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(4).text())
```

I've added the selectors according to my DEMO, please change it accordingily, because I don't have your HTML

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/57/)

Comment: +1 Nice job ... I also going to post this answer but you have posted quickly ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to access *5th column in 3rd row*,

You can use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector like

```
var value= $("#table tr:eq(2) td:eq(4)").text();
```

Side note: [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is used for accessing the value of form controls.