# How to copy a row from a table dynamically generated through a button inside a row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I hope you have a Nice day, I have the following code that dynamically generates a table from the result of a database query, basically it is a list of products:

```
$(".outer_div").append(
    '<div class="table-responsive"><table id= "r_table" class = "table table-checkable dataTable no-footer "></table></div class="table-responsive">'
  );
  let table = $("#r_table");

  let secRow = $(document.createElement("tr"));

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
      secRow.append(cellHead.text("Código"));
      table.append(secRow);
    } else if (i == 1) {
      let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
      secRow.append(cellHead.text("Proveedor"));
      table.append(secRow);
    } else if (i == 2) {
      let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
      secRow.append(cellHead.text("Producto"));
      table.append(secRow);
    } else if (i == 3) {
      let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
      secRow.append(cellHead.text("Precio"));
      table.append(secRow);
    } else if (i == 4) {
      let cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
      secRow.append(cellHead.text("Acciones"));
      table.append(secRow);
    }
  }

  $.each(datos, (index, value) => {

    let row = $(document.createElement("tr")).attr(
      "id",
      value["id"] + "row"
    );
    let secRow = $(document.createElement("tr"));



    for (let prop in value) {

      let cell = $(document.createElement("td")).attr(
        "id",
        value["id"] + "menu"
      );
      $("th").css("background-color", "#1bc5bd");


      cell.text(value[prop]);
      row.append(cell);
    }
    row.append(
      //Boton de agregar
      '<td><center><button onclick="cloneRow(\"'+'1row'+'\")"  class="envio btn btn-link-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button></center></td>'
    );




    table.append(row);

  });
```

But I want to achieve that, in what of the button that is generated in each row in the actions column, when I click it, copy the data of the entire row and save it to another table that must be generated in another form to then send it through an ajax to another part.

Here I leave the image of the table that is generated dynamically with the buttons

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH7ux.jpg)

And this would be the table where specify the row in question by clicking on the button of the specific row

```
<table id="results"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300836/get-value-of-a-specific-row-of-a-table-using-jquery) as potentially related. It uses jQuery to get specific values from a table, of course bear in mind that the index begins with 0. Change the values to more unique ones and see how it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event handler for the cloning directly to the table. Like so:

```
$('#myProductsTable').on('click', 'button', function() { // do sth });
```

That way the same button can be "reused" in the results table with a different behaviour:

```
$('#myResultsTable').on('click', 'button', function() { // do sth different});
```

wokring example:

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i ++) {
 let $row = $('<tr><td>ROW '+i+'</td><td><button>add '+i+'</button></td></tr>');
 $('#products tbody').append($row);
}

$('#products').on('click', 'button', function() {
 let $row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
  $row.find('button').text('remove');
 $('#results').append( $row );
});

$('#results').on('click', 'button', function() {
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
<thead><tr><th>my Products</th></tr></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="results">
<thead><tr><th>my Results</th></tr></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```